# How to select specified rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question on a how to select a row/rows in MySQL. My table is like this:
    candidate number, position, name, votes.

```
01, president, ramos, 3
02, president, bacon, 5
03, vice president, grey, 2
04, vice president, macapagal, 1
```

How to can display the candidate number and name in a certain position (president, vice president) with the highest votes.

The outcome that I want is:

```
02, president, bacon, 5
03, vice president, grey, 2
```

Comment: ORDER BY votes DESC? But why is ramos not on 2:nd place?

Comment: See [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Comment: i only want to display the winners in every position

Comment: What do you want to do if the vote count is the same between two records of the same position?

Comment: display vote in case of a tie or same number of vote in a certain position. is it possible? sorry, i'm just a newbie to mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select candidate_number, position, name, votes
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.position = t1.position
                    and t2.votes > t1.votes)
```

I.e. return rows where nobody with same position has more votes.

Comment: @iamjf: Let's hope it does. For the learning purpose it would have been better, you had only been given the algorithm and had had to write the query yourself. Keep in mind: always find the algorithm first ("where nobody with same position has more votes" or "where *not exists* anybody with the same position but a higher vote"), then write the query.

Comment: thanks for that. I'll keep it in mind. thanks again.